# После if код не работает

Tags: python, telebot

После `if` код не работает.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Create User")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("❓ Задать вопрос")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}!".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
    
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def func(user):
        if(user.text) == ('Create User'):
            mesg = bot.send_message(user.chat.id, text ='Print your Name')

            #От сюда уже не работает
            @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
            def funcn(username):
                nnn = username.text
                bot.send_message(user.chat.id, (nnn))
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, в вашем коде есть проблема с вложенным обработчиком сообщений. У вас он не будет вызван через декоратор `@bot.message_handler`, потому что вы пытались поместить его в другой обработчик сообщений

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Create User")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("❓ Задать вопрос")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, 
{0.first_name}!".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Create User')
    def create_user(message):
    mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Print your Name')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)  # Перехоплює всі інші текстові 
повідомлення
def handle_text(message):
    nnn = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn)
```

В этом коде есть три разных обработчика сообщений: один для команды `/start`, один для сообщения `Create User`и один для всех других текстовых сообщений. Такой подход позволит вам лучше управлять различными типами сообщений.